# Using DataRow From DataTable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have no deeply knowledge in VB.Net,

My question is: what does this code mean and do:

```
var_str = {dr("Column_name").ToString, "value"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just creates an array of strings, like so:

```
Dim myArray = {
      "value 1",
      "value 2"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Esko, I understood, Thank You!